# Spark SQL program running slow for any memory config

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am running a Spark SQL application written in JAVA on an EMR cluster. I have tried various options of memory but still not able to bring down the execution time.

The JAR is deployed to the cluster and i have tried the following options on a EMR cluster with 1 MASTER node 3 CORE Nodes and 3 TASK nodes [All are m4.4x large instance type]

I am using spark-submit to run my JAR from command line.

```
spark-submit --class <ClassPath of Main>  --master yarn   --executor-memory 19G   --num-executors 17   MyCode.jar
spark-submit --class <ClassPath of Main>  --master yarn   --executor-memory 50G   --num-executors 5   MyCode.jar
spark-submit --class <ClassPath of Main>  --master yarn   --executor-memory 40G   --num-executors 5   MyCode.jar
spark-submit --class <ClassPath of Main>  --master yarn   --executor-memory 2G   --num-executors 20   MyCode.jar
spark-submit --class <ClassPath of Main>  --master yarn   MyCode.jar
```

All the above executions took more than 3 hrs best ones were one without any memory args and the first one with 17 executors and 19G memory. But still very slow.

The Input is a list of parquet files that has about 10M rows and 18 columns each row.

I have also tried by changing the number of parquet files as input. 
i.e; 
10 million rows spread across 25 files
10 million rows spread across 5 files
10 million rows spread across 3 files

the larger file size also seem to slow down the performance of the application.

The avg input size is 1 G of parquet files.

Java Code snippets are as follows:

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appname("test").getOrCreate();

StructType schema = getSchemaForTable(input);

DataSet<Row> inFiles=spark.read().option("header",false).schema(schema).parquet(InputFolderInS3);

inFiles.createOrReplcaeTempView("TABLE1");

DataSet<Row> oneDataSet = spark.sql("select col1, col2 from TABLE1 where key IN (val1,val2,val3)");
oneDataSet.write().mode("overwrite").parquet(s3TargetForOne);

DataSet<Row> twoDataSet = spark.sql("select col1, col2 from TABLE1 where key NOT IN (select key from TABLE1 where <condition>)");
twoDataSet.write().mode("overwrite").parquet(s3TargetForTwo);

DataSet<Row> threeDataSet = spark.sql("select col5, col6 from TABLE1 where key IN (val1,val2,val3)");
threeDataSet.write().mode("overwrite").parquet(s3TargetForThree);

DataSet<Row> fourDataSet = spark.sql("select col5, col6 from TABLE1 where key NOT IN (select key from TABLE1 where <condition>)");
fourDataSet.write().mode("overwrite").parquet(s3TargetForFour);
```

Need Suggestion to optimize the code / configuration for spark to boost the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the SQL itself. I had inner queries in the where clause that slowed down the process. I found this out by referring to the SparkUI->SQL tab. Herei saw that there was a broadCastLoop that was running for each row for my outer query. I fixed the SQL and the time came down to 56 seconds for 1G of data.